# Remove uploaded build from apple store account

Tags: ios, submission

I have uploaded one build with 1.0 in test flight. Now again I am uploading with same version number but I am getting error message this time.

Though I have not submitted or published game in apple store then why I can't able to upload new build with same version number.

Please give me some suggestion for this because I don't want to update my version number to 1.1 at present state.

How to remove already uploaded, non submitted build from apple store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the version number as is but change the build number. Every build you submit has to have different build number but version number has to change with publish status

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. actually I don't have source code access at present and I want to submit app. I have apple account so how to remove already uploaded build from it?

Comment: Go to build settings section of your app and try from there but I don't think it will allow you to delete. Even if it allows you to delete the build you can only upload new build with new build number. That means you need code access to change your build number

Comment: If nothing is changed in your build then just promote that build to production but if something is changed it has to have a different build number

Comment: Anyways App Store review team is on holiday break till 29th December, they won't be reviewing new builds. So you have time to upload new build

Comment: Agree, there is no need of submitting App between 22-29 December. Enjoy :D